# Split screen containers with scrolling

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to create a web page in html/css that will split the width of the screen in 2, will keep the height at 100% with enabled scrolling, will always keep it that way, and which will have overflow content that will scroll horizontally and vertically. The image below shows a basic diagram of what I want to do:[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can **use `flex`** to `wrap` div to set them side by side and style box as below:

```css
.wrap{display:flex;}
.box{
height: 100vh;
    width: 50vw;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">

  </div>
  <div class="box">

  </div>
</div>
```

**You can use `inline-block`**

```css
.box{
  display:inline-block;
  height: 100vh;
   width: 49%;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Been struggling with this for longer than I would like to admit, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this easy and simple

```css
.container-main {
    max-width: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    background: #EFF0F1;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="container-main">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="container-main">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

it will add vertical and horizontal as well

Answer (score 1):

Would it need to look like this to stack one on top of the other?

```css
.wrap{display:flex;}
.box{
height: 50vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">

  </div>
  <div class="box">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Main point are below**

*A div in which you want to add scrolling:*
**Follow these step: **
*

1. add height and width property
2. add overflow:scroll property
3. Add display:flex in wrapper div

---

**Here is an simple example**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

    .div1{
        width: 18%;
    }
    .div_to_scroll{
        width: 56%;
        height: 100vh;
       overflow-x: scroll;
       background: #EFF0F1;
       margin:0 10px;
       padding: 10px;
       font-size: 30px;
        
    }
    .div3{
        width: 18%;
    }
    .wrapper{
        display: flex;
    }
</style>
</head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="div1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="div_to_scroll">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="div3">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            
        
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

this should be roughly what you need

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
.display {
height: 1000px;
width: 95%;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: scroll;
padding: 20px;
background: white;
border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="display" >

            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="display" >

            </div>
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```